# Search documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I'm trying to find documentation on accessing a MySQL database from Ruby. The search box only searches questions, whille the tags box only matches tag names (maybe aliases or descriptions too). How can I search the full text of the documentation?

Comment: Your best bet is to avoid the search entirely. It has not once provided even *remotely* what I'm looking for. Use google instead. For example: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=site:stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby+mysql

Comment: I've found the SO search system to be better than Google for some things, notably searching for tags. You just need to learn the advanced operators

Comment: If you need advanced operators to make the search give you even remotely relevant results, it's a broken design.

Comment: I almost always use advanced operators, at least the - operator

Comment: I'm curious why you want to search SO Docs specifically, instead of the whole Internet.

Comment: Improving search is high on our list of priorities. The next step is upgrading to latest version of Elasticsearch. Unfortunately, that involves [many breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking-changes-5.0.html) and projects besides Documentation. The good news is that it includes a number of features that could make search better across the board.